# Disconnecting mousedown/mousemove on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dom-events

I've built some rudimentary drawing tools on top of a leaflet map. I can attach a `mousedown` event and use it to draw polylines and polygons. After I'm down drawing, I can disconnect the `mousedown` event and everything works perfectly.

I've tried doing the same thing with a freehand drawing tool that uses that `mousemove` event to add data to an array. When I try to disconnect the `mousedown`, `mousemove` events, I can click the map and it's as if I never disabled it.

I've created a Plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/mFudKj4EICEZ1BgIMzNw

I apologize that there is just a gray block and not an actual map, but I didn't want to be wasting bandwidth for Cloudmade's servers for just a demo.

Comment: This is really cool, except I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Could you please provide more information on what's broken so users can better diagnose and help you fix it.

Comment: The problem was (I managed to hack around it) that the event handler was not getting disconnected. The hack was to disconnect all event handlers on the map element. It worked and I can now draw using all methods on a map (point, polyline, polygon and freehand). More investigation revealed that Leaflet was trying to handle mobile touch events and not just mouseup/mousedown. Those needed to be disconnected as well.

Comment: Awesome! Would love to check out the code if you could post back to this ticket.

Comment: Jim, could you put up a JSFiddle use case and post an issue on GitHub if it looks like a Leaflet issue?

Comment: To answer both requests, here is a quick example on GitHub: https://github.com/nobleach/leaflet-drawing-example The code is FAR from production ready. It works on a tablet but not in the browser.

Comment: @JimWharton Did you ever fix this?